# Run a process once inside a loop without that process repeating until told to

Tags: java, android, loops, if-statement, runnable

I have an Android service that is creating quite a bug for me. It is a runnable with an if/else statement. Basically, I need it to continuously run a check and execute the if continuously. It does this flawlessly. I need it the execute the else just one time until it detects the if again.

The problem I have is that it runs the else process in a loop also. How can I make the else statement run once while still detecting for the if?

Heres a code example...

```
         if(mTimer != null) {
            mTimer.cancel();
        } else {
            // recreate new
            mTimer = new Timer();
        }
        // schedule task
        mTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimeDisplayTimerTask(), 0, NOTIFY_INTERVAL);
    }



    class TimeDisplayTimerTask extends TimerTask {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // run on another thread
            mHandler.post(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // display toast

                    if(musicActive) {
                     // Set Ringer to vibrate

                  } else {
                        // Set Ringer to Normal


                  }
                }

            });
        }
```

the problem is that when the service is running and music isnt detected, people are unable to change their ringer setting because my app is still holding it inside the service. If I leave the }else{ empty, I get my desired result, but I need it to run that process one time to set the ringer to normal. I just dont need it to set the ringer to normal once every second.

Comment: This almost starts to sound like a job for a finite state machine

Comment: @ChrisStratton Somebody who is asking this question doesn't know what a finite state machine is. Trent, it sounds like you actually have a simple problem on your hands but I'm not positive what exactly you're asking. It can probably be solved with a "while" loop and by using variables in your conditional statement. Can you post your full code for the run()?

Comment: Also, what is mHandler.post doing - it looks like it's creating and running another Thread, but you're already inside of a Thread's run() method, hence creating an infinite loop. You should instead use a while() loop and execute continuously until some condition is met.

Comment: I added the rest of that code and tried to explain it a little better

Comment: Originally I had a while loop. The while loop works fine, but if I setup while(musicNotPlaying) { it loops this and I still cant only run it once}

Comment: @KyleM - yes, it's a learning opportunity that would require Trent to do some external reading.  A finite state machine is basically an *organized* way of doing what you propose with "variables in your conditional statement".

Comment: @ChrisStratton I've studied Automata theory, I don't disagree with your assertion. But OP is looking for concrete solutions and you're giving him advice to study computational theory. You can teach however you want to but I'm just telling you, that's not an effective teaching method. (Not trying to be a jerk... just saying)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is just to remember, something like this:

```
 boolean lastWasElse = false;


 mHandler.post(new Runnable() {

       @Override
       public void run() {

           if(true) {
                //  do this
                lastWasElse = false;
           } else if (!lastWasElse) {
                  // do once and then loop again, but if the answer is still "else" then skip this line.
                lastWasElse = true;
           }
       }
```

The trouble is where you store the lastWasElse variable - since you are constantly creating new runnables. You need to store one copy of that variable somewhere centrally and check it each time the task runs...

...or re-use the same `Runnable` constantly instead of creating new ones and store the variable inside the `Runnable`.

Comment: I wanted this to work so bad, but it didnt. It keeps running the else if statement.

Comment: @TrentPierce Make sure you declare the variable outside the method - I realized I accidentally deleted the method declaration but I've updated the post now.

Comment: I knew there had to be a simple solution I was overlooking. You just solved a huge headache I've had for a while. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I don't really see why you cant set ringer mode just once, before you start your timer loop :

```
myAudioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
// and then
// schedule task
mTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimeDisplayTimerTask(), 0, NOTIFY_INTERVAL);
```

More comments:

Your `TimerTask#run` alread runs in a background thread, you could do your job here without delegating to `Handler`'s thread, which I suppose is the UI thread in your case. In that case make sure you don't have anything potentially blocking UI here :

```
if(musicActive) {
    // do this
    // but watch out not to do blocking operations
}
```

Otherwise, you could only post your `// Display Toast` to Handler's UI thread and do your `if / else` in `TimerTask#run()` directly.

Comment: I cant set it before the loop because the app changes the ringermode. If(true) { // vibrate mode }else{ // normal mode }

Comment: the service detects music playing. If music is playing, it sets the ringer to vibrate. If music is not playing, it sets music to loud. I want to make it set the ringer to loud when music is not playing, but I want it to set it once and then leave it alone. Currently, it sets it once every second and people are unable to adjust their ringer away from normal mode with my service running